# Signature verification returns C0(CKR_SIGNATURE_INVALID)

Tags: cryptography, pki, pkcs#11, pkcs#10, safenet

I am trying to generate key pair using safenet sdk. Then I tried to sign the certificate informations with private key and verify using public key. But, the verification says signature is invalid. I checked whether generated public key and public key used to verify the information. They are the same.
How can i resolve the issue?

```
std::string Dongle::sign(char *password, char* data, char* enrollmentId) {
    CK_RV rv = CKR_OK;
    CK_SESSION_HANDLE hSession = CK_INVALID_HANDLE;
    
    LoadCryptoki(pkcs11_path);
    
    rv = GetFirstSlotId(&slotId);
    
    rv = C_OpenSession(slotId, (CKF_SERIAL_SESSION | CKF_RW_SESSION), NULL_PTR, NULL_PTR, &hSession);
    
    CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hPrivateKey = Dongle::generateKeyPairUtil(hSession, password, enrollmentId);
    
    std::string signature = Dongle::signUtil(hSession, hPrivateKey, password, data, enrollmentId);
    
    
    printf("OPERATION SUCCESS\n");
    //verify(password, signature, enrollmentId, );
    
end:
    if (hSession) fl->C_CloseSession(hSession);
    UnloadCryptoki();
    return signature;
}


CK_OBJECT_HANDLE Dongle::generateKeyPairUtil(CK_SESSION_HANDLE hSession, char *password, char *enrollmentId) {
    CK_RV rv = CKR_OK;
    CK_BBOOL    bFalse  = CK_FALSE;
    CK_BBOOL    bTrue   = CK_TRUE;
    CK_KEY_TYPE keyType = CKK_RSA;
    
    CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hPublicKey  = CK_INVALID_HANDLE;
    CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hPrivateKey = CK_INVALID_HANDLE;
    
    std::string labelPub = std::string("public") + enrollmentId;
    std::string labelPriv = std::string("private") + enrollmentId;
    
    
    CK_UTF8CHAR * labelPublic  = convertToCK_UTF8CHAR(labelPub);  //Label of public key.
    CK_UTF8CHAR * labelPrivate = convertToCK_UTF8CHAR(labelPriv); //Label of private key.
    
    // Setup public key attributes.
    CK_OBJECT_CLASS  classPublicKey = CKO_PUBLIC_KEY;
    CK_ULONG         vecModulusBits[] = { 2048 };
    CK_BYTE          publicExponent[] = { 0x01, 0x00, 0x01 };
    
    CK_ATTRIBUTE publicKeyTemplate[] =
    {
        { CKA_CLASS,            &classPublicKey,    sizeof(classPublicKey)      },
        { CKA_LABEL,            labelPublic,        strlen((char*)labelPublic)  },
        { CKA_KEY_TYPE,         &keyType,           sizeof(keyType)             },
        { CKA_TOKEN,            &bTrue,             sizeof(bTrue)               },
        { CKA_PRIVATE,          &bFalse,            sizeof(bFalse)              },
        { CKA_MODULUS_BITS,     &vecModulusBits[0], sizeof(vecModulusBits[0])   },
        { CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT,  &publicExponent,    sizeof(publicExponent)      },
        { CKA_VERIFY,            &bTrue,             sizeof(bTrue)              }
    };
    
    // Setup private key attributes.
    CK_OBJECT_CLASS  classPrivateKey = CKO_PRIVATE_KEY;
    CK_ATTRIBUTE privateKeyTemplate[] =
    {
        { CKA_CLASS,            &classPrivateKey,   sizeof(classPrivateKey)     },
        { CKA_LABEL,            labelPrivate,       strlen((char*)labelPrivate) },
        { CKA_KEY_TYPE,         &keyType,           sizeof(keyType)             },
        { CKA_TOKEN,            &bTrue,             sizeof(bTrue)               },
        { CKA_PRIVATE,          &bTrue,             sizeof(bTrue)               },
    };
    
    // Setup mechanism to generate an RSA key pair.
    CK_MECHANISM mechanism;
    memset (&mechanism, 0, sizeof (mechanism));
    mechanism.mechanism = CKM_RSA_PKCS_KEY_PAIR_GEN;
    
    // Login to the token with a user password.
    C_Login(hSession, CKU_USER, (CK_UTF8CHAR_PTR)password, strlen(password));
    
    // Try to find the two RSA keys with a specific label using the FindObject() function.
    hPrivateKey = FindObjects(hSession, privateKeyTemplate, DIM(privateKeyTemplate));
    hPublicKey  = FindObjects(hSession, publicKeyTemplate,  DIM(publicKeyTemplate));
    
    // Generate a new RSA key pair if an RSA key with the same label doesn't exist on the token.
    if ( ! (hPublicKey && hPrivateKey) )
    {
        printf("Wait for RSA key pair generation ... \n");
        rv = C_GenerateKeyPair(hSession, &mechanism, publicKeyTemplate, 7, privateKeyTemplate, 5, &hPublicKey, &hPrivateKey);
        
        if (rv == CKR_OK) {
            printf("OPERATION SUCCESS. Key Pair Generated Successfully.\n");
        }
    }
    
    else {
        printf("Key Pair Already Exists \n");
    }
    
end:
    C_Logout(hSession);
    return hPrivateKey;
}



std::string Dongle::signUtil(CK_SESSION_HANDLE hSession, CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hPrivateKey, char* password, char* data, char* enrollmentId) {
    //std::cout<<"data is: " << *data;
    CK_RV retCode = CKR_OK;
    
    int       isPaddingRequired = 0;
    int       isDataFromUser = 0;
    
    CK_MECHANISM mech;
    CK_BYTE pSigData[3000];
    CK_BYTE sign[2048];
    
#ifndef PKCS11_V1
    CK_ULONG usSigLen = sizeof(pSigData);
#else
    CK_ULONG usSigLen = 0;
#endif
    char *pInputData = 0;
    unsigned long ulInputDataLen = strlen(data);
    std::cout << "length: " << ulInputDataLen;
    CK_BYTE_PTR pInData = (CK_BYTE_PTR)data;
    
    
    std::cout << "Mechanism: [6]SHA256-RSA" <<std::endl;
    
    retCode = C_Login(hSession, CKU_USER, (CK_UTF8CHAR_PTR)password, strlen(password));
    
    mech.mechanism       = CKM_SHA256_RSA_PKCS;
    mech.pParameter      = 0;
    mech.ulParameterLen  = 0;
    isDataFromUser       = 0;
    
    
    if( retCode == CKR_OK )
    {
        if( isPaddingRequired )
        {
            for(unsigned long ulLoop=ulInputDataLen; ulLoop<64; ++ulLoop)
            {
                pInData[ulLoop] = 0;
            }
            ulInputDataLen = 64;
        }
    }
    
    
    if (retCode == CKR_OK)
    {
        retCode = C_SignInit(hSession, &mech, hPrivateKey);
    }
    
    CK_ULONG usInLen = (CK_ULONG)ulInputDataLen;
    
    // get the signature length
    if(retCode == CKR_OK)
    {
        retCode = C_Sign(hSession, pInData, usInLen, (CK_BYTE_PTR)NULL_PTR, &usSigLen);
    }
    std::cout << "sig length:  \n";
    std::cout << usSigLen;
    
    // get the signature
    if(retCode == CKR_OK)
    {
        retCode = C_Sign(hSession, pInData, usInLen, (CK_BYTE_PTR)pSigData, &usSigLen);
    }
    
    std::string returnSignature = "";
    std::string tempString = "";
    std::cout << "return code: \n";
    std::cout << retCode;
    if( (retCode == CKR_OK) && usSigLen )
    {
        std::cout << "Signed Data " << std::endl << "(hex) ";
        //returnSignature = base64_encode(pSigData,usSigLen);
        //WriteBinaryFile(signfile, (char *)pSigData, usSigLen);
        for(unsigned long ulLoop=0; ulLoop<usSigLen; ++ulLoop)
        {
            char pBuffer[25];

            sprintf(pBuffer, "%02x", pSigData[ulLoop]);
            std::cout << pBuffer;

            //returnSignature += pBuffer;
        }
        returnSignature = (char *)pSigData;
        returnSignature = base64_encode(pSigData, usSigLen);
        std::cout << "returned signature: \n";
        std::cout << returnSignature;
    }
    char arr[returnSignature.length() + 1];
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeof(arr); x++) {
            arr[x] = returnSignature[x];
        }
    verify(password,data,enrollmentId,pSigData,256,2048);
    
    // Release memory
    if( pInputData )
    {
        delete pInputData;
    }
    
    return returnSignature;
}



void Dongle::verify(char *password, char* data, char* enrollmentId, CK_BYTE_PTR signature, CK_ULONG sigLen, CK_ULONG sigDataLen) {
    CK_BBOOL    bFalse  = CK_FALSE;
    CK_BBOOL    bTrue   = CK_TRUE;
    CK_KEY_TYPE keyType = CKK_RSA;
    std::string labelPub = std::string("public") + enrollmentId;
    
    CK_UTF8CHAR * labelPublic  = convertToCK_UTF8CHAR(labelPub) ;  //Label of public key.
    
    // Setup public key attributes.
    CK_OBJECT_CLASS  classPublicKey = CKO_PUBLIC_KEY;
    CK_ULONG         vecModulusBits[] = { 2048 };
    CK_BYTE          publicExponent[] = { 0x01, 0x00, 0x01 };
    CK_ATTRIBUTE publicKeyTemplate[] =
    {
        { CKA_CLASS,            &classPublicKey,    sizeof(classPublicKey)      },
        { CKA_LABEL,            labelPublic,        strlen((char*)labelPublic)  },
        { CKA_KEY_TYPE,         &keyType,           sizeof(keyType)             },
        { CKA_TOKEN,            &bTrue,             sizeof(bTrue)               },
        { CKA_PRIVATE,          &bFalse,            sizeof(bFalse)              },
        { CKA_MODULUS_BITS,     &vecModulusBits[0], sizeof(vecModulusBits[0])   },
        { CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT,  &publicExponent,    sizeof(publicExponent)      },
        { CKA_VERIFY,            &bTrue,             sizeof(bTrue)              }
    };
    CK_RV rv = CKR_OK;
    CK_SESSION_HANDLE hSession = CK_INVALID_HANDLE;
    
    LoadCryptoki(pkcs11_path);
    
    rv = GetFirstSlotId(&slotId);
    
    rv = C_OpenSession(slotId, (CKF_SERIAL_SESSION | CKF_RW_SESSION), NULL_PTR, NULL_PTR, &hSession);
    CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hPublicKey  = CK_INVALID_HANDLE;
    hPublicKey  = FindObjects(hSession, publicKeyTemplate,  DIM(publicKeyTemplate));
    /* Verify the signature created by C_Sign. First we will verify that the
     * same Cryptoki library was able to trust itself.
     *
     * C_VerifyInit will begin the verify operation, by specifying what mechanism
     * to use (CKM_ECDSA, the same as the sign operation) and then specifying
     * which public key handle to use.
     */
    CK_RV retCode = CKR_OK;
    CK_MECHANISM mechanism;
    memset (&mechanism, 0, sizeof (mechanism));
    mechanism.mechanism = CKM_SHA256_RSA_PKCS ;
    retCode = C_VerifyInit( hSession,
                            &mechanism,
                            hPublicKey );
    ;

    /* Given the signature and it's length, the Cryptoki will use the public key
     * to see if the sender can be trusted. If C_Verify returns CKR_OK, it means
     * that the sender of the message has the same private key as the private key
     * that was used to generate the public key, and we can trust that the
     * message we received was from that sender.
     *
     * Note that we are not using the actual message, but the digest that we
     * created earlier of the message, for the verification.
     */
    if(retCode == CKR_OK) {
        retCode = C_Verify( hSession,
                           (CK_BYTE_PTR)data,
                           sigDataLen,
                           signature,
                           sigLen );
    }
    std::cout << "sig Data len: \n";
    std::cout << sigDataLen;
    std::cout << "sigLen: \n";
    std::cout << sigLen;
    std::cout << "return code is: \n";
    std::cout << retCode;
                                        
    if( retCode == CKR_OK )
    {
        std::cout << "The signature of the digest was verified with the" \
        " public key and can be trusted.\r\n";
    } else
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to verify the signature with the given public" \
                        " key, the message cannot be trusted.\r\n";
    }
    
}
```